# Select row if any of two conditions (one in WHERE clause and another in HAVING clause) are met

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where I show two columns: email and number of devices that are associated to that email (one to many relationship).

I then have a search box where I want to filter the results shown in the table. I want to use the content in the search box to check if it matches either the email or the devices count, therefore I tried first something like this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(d.id)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN devices d ON u.id = d.fk_user
WHERE email ILIKE '%jo%' OR COUNT(d.id)::text ILIKE '%jo%'
GROUP BY email
```

And when I realized I had to use the second condition in the having clause, I changed it to this:

```
SELECT email, COUNT(d.id)
FROM users u LEFT JOIN devices d ON u.id = d.fk_user
WHERE email ILIKE '%jo%'
GROUP BY email
HAVING COUNT(d.id)::text ILIKE '%jo%'
```

But of course it doesn't work either because there is no longer an OR that matches one condition or another.

How could I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing, or make it a CTE

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT email, COUNT(d.id) as count_did
FROM users u LEFT JOIN devices d ON u.id = d.fk_user
GROUP BY email
)x
WHERE email ILIKE '%jo%' OR count_did::text ILIKE '%jo%'
```

Not sure you really want to LIKE a number though, but I left your logic in

Answer (score 1):

Doing this with `HAVING` won't work. You can however use a subquery to get the counts before filtering:

```
SELECT email, count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT fk_user, COUNT(id) AS count
  FROM devices
  GROUP BY fk_user
) AS d ON u.id = d.fk_user
WHERE email ILIKE '%jo%' OR count::text ILIKE '%jo%'
```